# Self-destructing constructor == Singleton?

Tags: python, design-patterns, singleton

I've seen a few ways to create singletons in Python, but they all seem to have some drawback or another.  I just invented a way myself, and I'd like to know what's wrong with it :).

```
class Singleton(object):
    def __init__(self, cls, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance = cls(*args, **kwargs)

        def blocked(doppelganger, *args, **kwargs):
            raise RuntimeError("singleton")

        cls.__init__ = blocked

    def getInstance(self):
        return self.instance


class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x


a = Singleton(A, 10)
```

This works by handing a class to `Singleton`, which then instantiates it, then hobbles it by causing its constructor to raise a runtime exception.  The main drawback I can see is that this pattern will only prevent more instances from being created, but doesn't guarantee that there is only one instance out there.  It can also hobble any class at all, which is probably a bad idea.

These two drawbacks can be solved by un-abstracting the behavior into each class that wants to be a singleton.  For example, the definition of `blocked` and its assignment to `self.__init__` can be the last lines of `A`'s constructor.  Then `A` can only ever be instantiated once, though some other mechanism would need to place the single instance somewhere where clients can get to it.

Are there any other drawbacks to this approach?

Comment: one small point : `__init__` is not a constructor really, it is an initializer - the python construct is `__new__`. And there is nothing to stop me subclassing A with it's own `__init__` method - so `A.__init__` is never executed.

Comment: The downside of your way of dealing with a singleton is that, if I was only looking at the code for class A then I would no be able to tell that it is meant to be a singleton.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 Would the idea be to hijack ``A.__init__`` for execution in a subclass?  You could still only ever execute it once, right?

Comment: @Dunes, good point.  The less abstract approach of self-destructing the initializer (not constructor! :-D) would solve that issue too, right?

Comment: It's often useful to have the constructor of a singleton return the one-and-only instance if there is one or create one and return it if there isn't one already rather than raising an exception. This allows the (single) instance to be used in many places, which is useful because this pattern is often used for effectively global objects.

Comment: @RoniChoudhury - Not sure what you mean about hijacking `A.__init__`...

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 I guess I didn't understand what you mean about subclassing A with its own ``__init__`` in such a way that ``A.__init__`` is never executed.

Comment: @RoniChoudhury - if I create a class called B which subclasses Singleton, but which has it's own `__init__` method, then the `__init__` on the Singleton class wont be executed unless it is explicitly executed.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 Ah, I see.  That's true but this is Python - if someone wants to subclass from ``Singleton`` and not invoke the superclass ``__init__``, thereby breaking the semantics of the exact thing they're subclassing... well, it's their party :-P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It breaks inheritance:

```py
class Singleton(object):
    def __init__(self, cls, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance = cls(*args, **kwargs)

        def blocked(doppelganger, *args, **kwargs):
            raise RuntimeError("singleton")

        cls.__init__ = blocked

    def getInstance(self):
        return self.instance


class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(B, self).__init__(x)
        self.y = y


a = Singleton(A, 10)
b = Singleton(B, 10, 20)  # Raises RuntimeError
```

In this case: `Singleton(B, 10, 20)`, will call `A.__init__` which raises an exception.

**Edit**: For clarification, you might think "*well this is expected. Since A is a singleton, we shouldn't be able to subclass them.*"

But here's the thing:

```py
b = Singleton(B, 10, 20)
a = Singleton(A, 10)
```

works.